# File copied from NTFS drive greyed out and inaccessible

Tags: macos, filesystems, finder

The file's contents are confirmed to be correct, and it has read, write, and executable filesystem flags set.

The file is grayed out in Finder, and cannot be opened or read. (the file in question is an ubuntu .iso file, and virtual box refuses to mount it)

Answer (score 3):

This is apparently an issue independent of the underlying HFS+ or APFS filesystem.

`xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo <file>`

was the solution that worked for me.

[this article](https://buxty.com/b/2012/08/how-to-fix-ghost-files-in-the-finder/) helped.